# How can I make horizontal scrollable in a bootstrap row? (two row)

Tags: html, css, scroll, bootstrap-4, row

If I use one row, it works. See this script :

html :

```
<div class="testimonial-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">7</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.testimonial-group > .row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

The result like this :

[image]

But If I use two row, it does not works. There exist two scrollbar. The script like this :

html :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">7</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">7</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.testimonial-group > .row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

The result like this :

[image]

There exist two scrollbar. I want only one scrollbar. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overflow should be on the parent instead of the rows..

```
.testimonial-group {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.testimonial-group > .row {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Or you can simply use the Bootstrap `overflow-auto` and `flex-nowrap` classes for this: 
https://www.codeply.com/go/5gtLhulVtk

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent_div"> 
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```